# Alternatives to eval `ssh-agent` and exec ssh-agent bash

Tags: linux, shell, exec, eval, ssh-agent

Running either of these commands seems to start an SSH agent process successfully:

```
eval `ssh-agent`
```

OR

```
exec ssh-agent bash
```

I'm partial to the first one, because the second `exec` replaces the shell. Obviously the second, uses `eval` which is frowned upon by some, but I don't see alternatives.

---

*My questions are:*

1. Does `exec` have any negative side effects when replacing the shell or indeed any side effects at all? Are my concerns about using `exec` warranted?
2. I don't have an issue using `eval` but, out of interest what alternative commands are there **without scripts or functions** (and without `exec` or `eval`) to start an ssh-agent process in one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a "safe" use of `eval`, at least to the extent that you trust `ssh-agent` to output nothing but simple, hard-coded assignments similar to

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/var/folders/...; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=xxxxx; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid xxxxx;
```

The output of `ssh-agent` is specifically designed to be passed to `eval`, and let's face it: if `ssh-agent` wanted to do harm, it could do so in a quieter fashion.

The downside to using `exec` is that the new shell that replaces the original shell may not be identical; the environment is inherited, but some shell settings not found in `.bashrc` may be different. However, if you put `exec ssh-agent bash` *in* your `.bashrc` (especially as the last line), there there isn't really any opportunity for your shell's configuration to diverge from whatever `.bashrc` did. (There is also the possibility that you have non-idempotent code in your `.bashrc`, meaning that executing it twice will result in different behavior than having only executed it once. But again, that's unlikely and easily auditable.)

Comment: Thanks that answers Q1 and largely Q2 - as you say "`ssh-agent` is specifically designed to be passed to `eval`" it just strikes me as strange that there isn't really another mechanism to do this - whether hacky or not, like a 'Googlewhack'. I see the question is on hold, perhaps it should have been on another Stack site